# http host and port information in HandleFunc

Tags: go, httprequest, httpserver, go-http

I am try to start multiple http servers listening on different ports in same package. In my test HandleFunc function I need to print our host and the port of information of the http server which served the request. How would I do that?

Here is my sample code:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "flag"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"

    "github.com/dineshgowda24/lb/backendserver/config"
)

func main() {
    c := flag.String("c", "config/config.json", "Please specify conf.json")
    flag.Parse()
    file, err := os.Open(*c)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Unable to open config file")
    }
    defer file.Close()
    decoder := json.NewDecoder(file)
    config := bconfig.BackendConfiguration{}
    err = decoder.Decode(&config)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Unable to decode conf.json file")
    }
    http.HandleFunc("/", handle)
    for _, s := range config.Servers {
        log.Printf("Started server at : %s : %s ", s.Host, s.Port)
        go func(host, port string) {
            if err := http.ListenAndServe(host+":"+port, nil); err != nil {
                log.Printf("Unable to start server at : %s : %s ", host, port)
            }
        }(s.Host, s.Port)
    }
    select {}
}

//How to get info of the server which served the request ??
func handle(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    response := "I came from " //need to get server info
    w.Write([]byte(response))
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
}
```

Comment: Use [http.ServerContextKey](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ServerContextKey) to retrieve the server from the request context and inspect the Addr field.

Comment: This worked thank you. Can you add the answer

Answer (score 5):

Use [http.LocalAddrContextKey](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#LocalAddrContextKey) to retrieve the server address from the request context.

In my comment I suggested to use the ServerContextKey, but the http.Server.Addr field isn't always set, such as when using [http.Server.Serve](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Serve) (and by extension http.Serve). The following example demonstrates that LocalAddrContextKey works with both http.ListenAndServe and http.Serve:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        ctx := r.Context()

        srvAddr := ctx.Value(http.LocalAddrContextKey).(net.Addr)

        fmt.Println(srvAddr)
    })

    ln, err := net.Listen("tcp", "127.0.0.1:3000")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    go func() { log.Fatal(http.Serve(ln, nil)) }()
    go func() { log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe("127.0.0.1:4000", nil)) }()

    resp, err := http.Get("http://localhost:3000")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    resp.Body.Close()

    resp, err = http.Get("http://localhost:4000")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    resp.Body.Close()

}

// Output:
// 127.0.0.1:3000
// 127.0.0.1:4000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get it from request host by using `r.Host` . ref : https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request

Comment: That field is controlled by the client and therefore untrustworthy.